# Generate JSON string from form on change to populate business-hours

Tags: javascript, html, json, string

I have the following html input's

```
<form id="test" role="form">
    <input class="form-control" data-day="monday" type="time" name="open" value="12:00">
    <input class="form-control" data-day="monday" type="time" name="close" value="20:00">
    <!-- Rest of the weekdays -->
    <input class="form-control" data-day="sunday" type="time" name="open" value="12:00">
    <input class="form-control" data-day="sunday" type="time" name="close" value="23:00">
</form>

<pre id="output"></pre>
```

i try to generate a JSON string based on the input ***(on change)***..
The problem with my code is that it update (and only) al the values of the other days when i change sunday.

if i make a change on the other day's nothing happens, i kinda get it why it fails, but breaking my head to long on it now.

```js
function toJSONString(form) {

  var daysObj = {}
  var hoursObj = {};
  var elements = form.querySelectorAll("input[type='time']");
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
    var element = elements[i];
    var days = element.dataset.day;
    var name = element.name;
    var value = element.value;

    //if (days) {
    //if (name) {
    hoursObj[name] = value;
    //}
    daysObj[days] = hoursObj;
    //}
  }

  return JSON.stringify(daysObj, null, 2);
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var form = document.getElementById("test");
  var output = document.getElementById("output");
  form.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var json = toJSONString(this);
    output.innerHTML = json;

  }, false);

});
```

```html
<form id="test" role="form">
  <input class="form-control" data-day="monday" type="time" name="open" value="12:00">
  <input class="form-control" data-day="monday" type="time" name="close" value="20:00">
  <!-- Rest of the weekdays -->
  <input class="form-control" data-day="sunday" type="time" name="open" value="12:00">
  <input class="form-control" data-day="sunday" type="time" name="close" value="23:00">
</form>

<pre id="output"></pre>
```

Comment: Thanks @t.niese for make it a snippet!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `input` event instead of `change` as a `change` event only occurs after an input loses focus. `input` events are triggered every time the input's value changes

```
form.addEventListener("input",function(){})
```

You are also using the same hours object for each day. And thus each iteration you are just changing the same object's `open` and `close` property.

You need to create a new object for `hoursObj` after you have set the last property for that object for that day, in your case after setting `close`

```
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
  //previous code
  //...

  if(name=="close"){
     hoursObj = {};
  }
}
```

Demo

```js
function toJSONString(form) {
  var daysObj = {}
  var hoursObj = {}
  var elements = form.querySelectorAll("input[type='time']");
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
    var element = elements[i];
    var days = element.dataset.day;
    var name = element.name;
    var value = element.value;
    hoursObj[name] = value;
    daysObj[days] = hoursObj;
    if(name=="close"){
      hoursObj = {};
    }
  }

  return JSON.stringify(daysObj);
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var form = document.getElementById("test");
  var output = document.getElementById("output");
  form.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var json = toJSONString(this);
    output.innerHTML = json;

  }, false);

});
```

```html
<form id="test" role="form">
  <input class="form-control" data-day="monday" type="time" name="open" value="12:00">
  <input class="form-control" data-day="monday" type="time" name="close" value="20:00">
  <!-- Rest of the weekdays -->
  <input class="form-control" data-day="sunday" type="time" name="open" value="12:00">
  <input class="form-control" data-day="sunday" type="time" name="close" value="23:00">
</form>

<pre><code id="output"></code></pre>
```

Comment: Thanks for sorting it out and +1 for the input tip!